# how to know if 2 bits can make xor java

Tags: java, if-statement, byte, bit

i have a 8 bit long value ( 1 byte ) called dividendo (with the value 0x98 = 10011000), i want to make a xor ( ^ ) between the 3 first bits from dividendo (100 ) and the value of variable div (0x5 = 101) so i can have this ( 001 ), the if sentence its trying to know if t and div have the same size in bits so they can make a xor, It is for a crc code in java

i want to do this:

```
    long t, res;
    long dividendo = 0x98;   
    long div = 0x5;
    for(int i=0; i< 8;i++ ){       // to extract bit by bit from a byte
     t=(dividendo   >>> (7-i));      
    if( div ^ t ) {
        res = t^div;
        System.out.println(Long.toHexString(res));
    }
```

Comment: Please rephrase. I don't understand what you want.

Comment: What is the data type of `res` and `t`?

Comment: i edited the question trying to explain myself better

Answer (score 2):

I think you could probably just say `if(div^t!=0)`, if I understand correctly what you are saying.

Comment: +1 for guessing what he meant. It makes sense if he's coming from C.